# Trouble with lpCommandLine in CreateProcess()

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

argI have some code:

```
CreateProcess(L"D:\\prog\\forLb1SPZ.exe",L"D:\\prog\\forLb1SPZ.exe D:\\1.txt",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi)
```

THis code is working, BUT... file is creating near the program (where this code is wrote) and has name "D" - the first symbol of argv[1]. What`s wrong?

Code in forLb1SPZ.exe

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int value;
  FILE *Ptr;

  Ptr=fopen("argv[1]","w");

  for(int i=0;i<20000;i++){
      value=rand();
    fprintf(Ptr,"%d i=%d \n",value,i);
  }

  fclose(Ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Code in lab2SPZ.exe (main program)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if(!CreateProcess(L"D:\\forLb1SPZ.exe","D:\\forLb1SPZ.exe D:\\1.txt",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
{printf( "creating fail\n");system("pause");return 0;}




printf("handle: %X\n", pi.hProcess);
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. Post real code. Don't pass const char* as lpCommandLine.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's `CreateProcess` that's creating that file, and not forLb1SPZ.exe?

Note:

1. You're using wide strings. If forLb1SPZ.exe uses ANSI strings, it might see a \0 after the D. If it should, say, open "D:\1.txt", it might see the file name as "D" (I'm not positive on this, but I imagine the OS doesn't convert the encoding. I might be wrong, and it does). Try using `CreateProcessA` and see if there's a difference.
2. The second argument must be a LPTSTR and not an LPCTSTR. You're passing a string literal, and according to the docs that string might be changed by `CreateProcess`. If that happens, you'll have undefined behavior, and possibly a crash.
3. You're passing the app name in both the first and second arguments. That's usually redundant. Is it intentional?

Comment: File is creating by forLb1SPZ.exe, but it appears in other dir. I tried to do like you said(about \0), but the problem is the same. In orLb1SPZ i tried to open `Ptr=fopen("D:\\1.txt","w");` and it was working. No difference after using `CreateProcessA`.

Comment: Could you please post the (real) code that creates the file in forLb1SPZ.exe? Since your `lpCurrentDirectory` in `CreateProcess` is NULL, forLb1SPZ.exe gets the current directory of the calling process. When we figure out how the full path turns to a "D", the problem will be solved.

Comment: Without "L" I get erorr 'error C2664: 'CreateProcessW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [26]' to 'LPWSTR''. Also without first parameter (using NULL) I get error in dbgheap.c file and program needs breaking... I don`t understand what I must to do =((

Comment: Keep the `L`, its fine. When you pass NULL as the first arg, you probably get a segfault due to my note #2 - use `WCHAR cmd[] = "the cmdline";` and pass `cmd` as the second param. Now, I still suspect the fact that you use Unicode strings in lab2SPZ and ANSI ones in forLb1SPZ. Please take a look at the `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` in the CreateProcess docs, and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but problem was in iostream library.... I deleted `#include "iostream"` and file was created correctly =)

Comment: Huh? what does `iostream` have to do with that? `fopen` comes from `stdio.h`, and I don't see any use of streams. Also, now that you mention it, I'd expect the (removed) include to look like `#include <iostream>`, note the angle brackets. Do you have your own version of `iostream`?

Comment: I was surprised too! I don`t have some different version of `iostream`, only standard one.